# Форма обратной связи на сайте

Tags: php, html

Сделал форму обратной связи на сайте. Форма приходит. Она состоит из 2 input и 1 textarea.Данные, которые введены в input отображаются в письме, а данные введенные в поле textarea - нет

html код:

```
<form action="test.php" class="form" method="post">

               <div class="input-group">
                   <input  placeholder="Имя*" class="input__form input__name" name="userName" type="text" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="300">
                   <input placeholder="e-mail*" class="input__form input__email" name="userEmail" type="text" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="450" required>
               </div>
                 <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Сообщение*" name="сообщение" id="textarea" name="message" cols="30" rows="10" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="600"></textarea>

<!--              <button type="submit" class="button__form" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="750">Отправить</button>-->

               <input type="submit" class="button__form" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="750" placeholder="Отправить">

            </form>
```

PHP Код

```
<?php


//Получим ланные с элемента формы

   $name = $_POST['userName'];
   $userEmail = $_POST['userEmail'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];


//обработаем полученные данные

   $name = htmlspecialchars($name);
   $userEmail = htmlspecialchars($userEmail);
   $message = htmlspecialchars($message);

   $name = urldecode($name);
   $userEmail = urldecode($userEmail);
   $message = urldecode($message);

   $name = trim($name);
   $userEmail = trim($userEmail);
   $message = trim($message);


//отправляем данные

   if (mail("fetishev.konstantin@yandex.ru",
           "Новое письмо с сайта",
           "Логин: ".$name."\n".
           "Почта: ".$userEmail."\n".
           "Сообщение: ".$message."\n".
           "From: kon.alex.fet@yandex.ru \r\n")
      ){
      echo("Письмо успешно отправленно");
   } else {
      echo("Есть ошибки! проверьте данные");
   }

?>
```

Comment: Удалите из html name="сообщение"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что дублируется атрибут name. `<textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Сообщение*" name="сообщение" id="textarea" name="message"`. В данном случае: сообщение и message. Если инфо не приходит в POST[message], значит оно находится в POST[сообщение]